# Como puedo generar una URL para visualizar un archivo(word, pdf, excel) con google docs viewer

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5 y me tope con esta forma de utilizar google docs viewer:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=AQUÍ URL DEL DOCUMENTO&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Mi problema radica en que no se como puedo generar u obtener una URL para mis archivos, los cuales guardo por el momento de forma local, dentro de la carpeta **storage** de laravel. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo, por que lo que entiendo es que necesitas urls que apunten a los archivos que estan en el storage? por que lo que podrias hacer el en la url pases como parametros el nombre del archivo y asi obtiene el archivo como tal

Comment: Así es @FuriosoJack es justo lo que quiero lograr, generar una URL que apunte a mi archivo en el storage, mas no se como realizar eso, es por esa razón que pido ayuda, no se como lograrlo

Comment: antes de darte la respuesta, Que tipo de archivos son? pdf, xml, ?

Comment: Son archivos word, excel y pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes crear la ruta

```
Route::get('/documento/{nombredelarchivo}/',
        [
          'uses'=>'Controller@generate',
          'as'=>'getDocument'
        ]);
```

El controlador seria de la siguiente manera

```
public function generate($nombreArchivo)
    {
        $archivo= storage_path($nombreArchivo);
        return response()->download($archivo);
    }
```

Obviamente esto es un ejemplo básico abria hacer la validación del nombre del archivo que existan también. Pero puedes probar con esto

Comment: Hola @FuriosoJack creo que respondiste una de mis cuestiones(tengo varias, pero no publico todas), pero no la que comentaba en el post, de la manera en que me apoyas es para descargar un archivo determinado, lo que yo buscaba era generar una URL a partir de un cierto archivo, ya que quiero usar el visor de documentos de google, que anexo en esta linea `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=AQUÍ URL DEL DOCUMENTO&embedded=true"></iframe>` es lo que esta en **src** quisiera generar urls para mis archivos y colocarla en ese **src**  de google para poder visualizar el archivo que quiera

Answer (score 0):

Si tu guardas con storage tus archivos pasandole como disco de destino el publico, estos son guardados en la carpeta storage/app/public, esta carpeta por defecto no es accesible públicamente por lo que tienes que hacer un link simbólico, debes de correr el siguiente comando.

php artisan storage:link

Si los archivos los subes manualmente puedes colocarlos en una carpeta del directorio publico. Te recomiendo que lo  hagas en la carpeta storage del directorio public, si no existe créala, como pasaría si hicieses el link simbólico.

Para generar una url se hace con estas funciones:

//sin storage, genera una direreccion con http://{dominio}/storage/a.doc
url('storage/a.doc')

//con storage, genera una dirección a /storage/a.doc
Storage::url('public/a.doc')

eso te generara un archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, mis archivos los guardo dentro de storage/app/public/carpeta/carpeta2/carpeta3, son distintas carpetas, pero enfocandome en una, como seria la linea de codigo para generar el link, ya he ejecutado el comando que me comentas y me dice que el directorio ha sido linkeado, mas no se que mas hacer

Comment: si tienes un archivo llamado a.doc en la carperta llamada **carpeta2**            

echo '<a href="'.url("storage/carpeta2/a.doc").'">link</a>';        

**url("storage/carpeta/a.doc")** genera la siguiente url              
**http://dominio.com/storage/carpeta2/a.doc**